# Удаление inline кнопок aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Создаю бота на питоне для телеграма с использованием библиотеки aiogram. Столкнулся с проблемой удаления inline кнопок сообщения. Мне нужно удалять кнопки при нажатии на них. Я пробовал удалять кнопки через метод edit_reply_markup, где заменял клавиатуру на другую без этой кнопки. Но поскольку кнопок две, при "удалении" одной появляется кнопка на другую

Мой код ниже

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.builtin import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData

callback_id = CallbackData("id", "button")

bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(CommandStart())
async def bot_start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "some text", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton("button1",callback_data=callback_id.new(button="button1"))).add(InlineKeyboardButton("button2",callback_data=callback_id.new(button="button2"))))

@dp.callback_query_handler(callback_id.filter(button="button1"))
async def ban(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.edit_text(call.message.html_text+"\nbutton1 deleted")
    #В следующей строке хочу удалить button1 (заменяю клавиатурой без button1), но не известно удалена ли button2
    await call.message.edit_reply_markup(InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton("button2",callback_data=callback_id.new(button="button2"))))

@dp.callback_query_handler(callback_id.filter(button="button2"))
async def ban(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.edit_text(call.message.html_text+"\nbutton2 deleted")
    #В следующей строке хочу удалить button2 (заменяю клавиатурой без button2), но не известно удалена ли button1
    await call.message.edit_reply_markup(InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton("button1",callback_data=callback_id.new(button="button1"))))


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Так что я получаю такой результат:[image: неправильно работает]

А мне нужно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Можно сделать проверку есть ли такая кнопка у клавиатуры на которую нажали.  call.message.reply_markup здесь она лежит

Comment: @oleksandrigo спасибо большое, все получилось!

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал вот такую функцию, работает отлично (плохого ничего пока не заметил).

```
# Remove Inline Button in Inline Menu
async def remove_inline_button(menu, button_callbacks: list):
    menu = menu['inline_keyboard']
    result = {'inline_keyboard': []}
    list_items_amount = 0

    for x in menu:
        result['inline_keyboard'].append([])

        for item in menu[list_items_amount]:
            if item['callback_data'] not in button_callbacks:
                result['inline_keyboard'][list_items_amount].append(item)

        list_items_amount += 1

    return result
```

Данный код удаляет кнопки из инлайн меню, по `callback_data`.
Использование:

```
menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(InlineKeyboardButton('Первая кнопка',
       callback_data='button_one')).add(InlineKeyboardButton('Вторая кнопка', 
       callback_data='button_two'))

menu = await remove_inline_button(menu, ['button_one'])

await bot.send_message(
    call.from_user.id, 'Меню для теста удаления кнопки!', reply_markup=menu)
```

На качество кода не претендую, сам новичок.

Answer (score 0):

`callback.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard` представляет собой обычный список `list`, так что можно удалять из него кнопки, как элементы из списка, например, с помощью `pop()`

```
callback.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard.pop(-1)
```

Это удаление последней кнопки

Comment: Метод .pop() и так по умолчанию удаляет последний элемент, если не указан индекс элемента для удаления)

Comment: @Step1709, спасибо за документацию, кэп, я знаю, но здесь я хотел показать, как можно просто удалять кнопки, а не пользоваться  списками, думаю, автор это и без меня умеет :)